# Why can't I install Kubuntu on my new Laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, software-installation, kubuntu, acer

So yesterday I received a new laptop with 512 GB of SSD and windows in it, I wanted to start with Linux so I downloaded Kubuntu. I installed in, customized it and the next day it came to my surprise that I could't enter because of beeing stuck in emergency mode. I tried installing it again and it freezed randomly. I tried with KDE Neon and happened the same.

Finally I have unistalled everything and put the partitions together in windows. Does anyone know why this happens and why I can't install Linux in my laptop.

My Laptop is an [Acer Swift3 SF314-41](https://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Document/User%20Manual/User%20Manual_Acer_1.0_A_A.pdf?acerid=636960930267251097&Step1=ULTRA-THIN&Step2=SWIFT&Step3=SF314-41&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_6) with an AMD Ryzen 5 and  a 512 GB SSD

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you checked you BIOS settings? Sometimes they cause some issues. Had similar problem in my Dell Precision 5530.

Comment: I thought that probably could be that, but I'm not really an expert so I don't know what do I have to touch

Comment: In my case it needed to turn off "secure boot" at change the boot mode to "legacy". But since you could boot from USB the boot mode might not be a problem.
Just wonder if the Ryzen 5 Graphic driver might be the issue.

Comment: Very likely that without exact error messages, and the computer now restored to Windows-only so you can't post logs and results of commands, we won't be able to answer.

Comment: Never hurts to disable secure boot, I've had it make things more difficult. As @ZeissIkon mentioned though, we need more details before being able to really help.

Comment: Someone in the Acer community told me to change SATA mode to AHCI, what do you think?